# How to set a range of possible zoom levels in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have 3 layers on a *leaflet map*, they are displayed or not according to the zoom level.

I'd like to set only **3 possible zoom levels**: for example, when a user clicks on the button to zoom in, it would go from zoom *1* to zoom *4* (without going through zoom 2 and 3)

Is it possible to do?

Comment: You could hook the `zoomend` event on the map and force a new zoom level if the one it's landed on isn't valid. You'd need to track what direction the zoom level was moving in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to restrict the zoom levels would be to override the [`setView`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-setview) method on your map that is used to handle all changes of zoom levels. The override would set an authorized zoom level when it detects that the one passed is invalid.

For example,

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.864, 2.345], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// allowed zoom levels
var allowZooms = [4, 8, 12];

map.setView = function(center, zoom, options) {
    // tests if the requested zoom is allowed
    if ((zoom) && (allowZooms.indexOf(zoom) === -1)) {
        // this._zoom is an internal value used to reference the current zoom level
        var ixCurZoom = allowZooms.indexOf(this._zoom);

        // are we zooming in or out?
        var dir = (zoom > this._zoom) ? 1 : -1;

        // pick the previous/next zoom
        if (allowZooms[ixCurZoom + dir]) {
            zoom = allowZooms[ixCurZoom + dir];
        } else {
            // or abort the zoom if we're out of bounds
            return this;
        }
    }

    // call the parent method
    return L.Map.prototype.setView.call(this, center, zoom, options);
}
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.864, 2.345], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


var allowZooms = [4, 8, 12];
map.setView = function(center, zoom, options) {
    if ((zoom) && (allowZooms.indexOf(zoom) === -1)) {
        var ixCurZoom = allowZooms.indexOf(this._zoom);
        var dir = (zoom > this._zoom) ? 1 : -1;
        if (allowZooms[ixCurZoom + dir]) {
            zoom = allowZooms[ixCurZoom + dir];
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }
    
    return L.Map.prototype.setView.call(this, center, zoom, options);
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.4/leaflet.css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.4/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```